# Splitting into x_train and y_train Recurrent Neural network using time steps

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Training a recurrent neural network to predict opening stock prices.

```
train = train.loc[:, ["Open"]].values

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train)
end_len = len(train_scaled)

X_train = []
y_train = []
timesteps = 40


# for i in range (timesteps, end_len)
for i in range(timesteps, end_len):
    X_train.append(train_scaled[i - timesteps:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_scaled[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
```

Struggling to understand the notation for the x_train.append line. I understand the theory behind time steps and how x_train and y_train are computed during the process, but how does the for loop encode that?

The specific line i am confused with is:

`X_train.append(train_scaled[i - timesteps:i, 0])`

I think the square brackets are a specific index of that scaled dataframe I made in previous steps, but say i = 45, what does "train_scaled[45-40:45,0]" mean?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works

Comment: To translate what that line is doing into English: starting at `i`, get the previous `timesteps` elements, not including `i` itself. The `, 0` part is indexing into the second dimension of the array.